# Installing matplotlib with conda fails with conda.exceptions.ResolvePackageNotFound

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

The julia package PyPlot.jl should normally installed conda and matplotlib automatically. However when importing PyPlot in julia I get the error:

```
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - conda==23.1.0
```

This error can be replicated independently from julia by running:

```
/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/bin/conda install -y matplotlib
# same error message as above
```

Downgrading conda to 23.1.0 and then installing matplotlib works, but I would like to avoid this step for my students.

Here is more information from the conda environment:

```
     active environment : None
       user config file : /root/.condarc
 populated config files : /root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/.condarc
                          /root/.condarc
          conda version : 23.7.2
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.12.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __glibc=2.36=0
                          __linux=5.15.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/pkgs
                          /root/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/envs
                          /root/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/23.7.2 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.10.12 Linux/5.15.0-47-generic debian/12 glibc/2.36
                UID:GID : 0:0
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

```
root@f1e8642ebf63:~/.julia/conda/3/x86_64# cat .condarc 
channels:
- conda-forge
```

Even if I use conda 23.7, it seems that one package depends on conda 23.1. How do I find out which package causes this problem?

Also using the verbose mode with `unsatisfiable_hints True` did not give more information.

```
root@f1e8642ebf63:~/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/bin# ./conda config --set unsatisfiable_hints True
root@f1e8642ebf63:~/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/bin# /root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/bin/conda  install -y matplotlib -v 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 316, in install
    unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 154, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 215, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 380, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._add_specs(ssc)
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 918, in _add_specs
    raise UnsatisfiableError({})
conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError: 
Did not find conflicting dependencies. If you would like to know which
packages conflict ensure that you have enabled unsatisfiable hints.

conda config --set unsatisfiable_hints True
            

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 64, in main_subshell
    exit_code = do_call(args, parser)
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 167, in do_call
    result = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 124, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 26, in execute
    install(args, parser, "install")
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 368, in install
    unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 154, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 215, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 380, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._add_specs(ssc)
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 874, in _add_specs
    conflicts = ssc.r.get_conflicting_specs(
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 1252, in get_conflicting_specs
    reduced_index = self.get_reduced_index(all_specs)
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 84, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 678, in get_reduced_index
    explicit_specs, features = self.verify_specs(explicit_specs)
  File "/root/.julia/conda/3/x86_64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 333, in verify_specs
    raise ResolvePackageNotFound(bad_deps)
conda.exceptions.ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - conda==23.1.0
```

Github issue: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/571